# Apache 2.4.33 Multiple IP restriction throwing error but single IP restriction works

Tags: apache-2.4

Apache 2.4.33.

We have the followings in a config file:

```
<Directory "/var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require ip 118.x.x.x
        <files *.mp3>
                Forcetype application/forcedownload
        </files>
        php_admin_value engine Off
</Directory>
```

To restrict multiple IPs if I put `Require ip 118.x.x.x 103.x.x.x 116.x.x.x` then when I try to restart the apache it fails and errors in the config file.

I also have tried the following format but did not work:

```
Require ip 118.x.x.x
Require ip 103.x.x.x
Require ip 116.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow specific IP addresses to access the site you should have:

```
<RequireAny>
  Require ip 118.x.x.x
  Require ip 103.x.x.x
  Require ip 116.x.x.x
</RequireAny>
```

A little more info you can find in Apache documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html
I have in mind this:

> The Require provides a variety of different ways to allow or deny access to resources. In conjunction with the RequireAll, RequireAny, and RequireNone directives, these requirements may be combined in arbitrarily complex ways, to enforce whatever your access policy happens to be.

Comment: That is strange! I tried that before and it did not work. But now it is working. Must have missed something critical.

Comment: Any idea why one of the IP works but others don't? I had checked the IPs from google which gives the face IPs.

Comment: Did you use `<RequireAny>` block with "Require ip" directives?

Comment: Yes, `AllowOverride None` followed by `<RequireAny>`.

Comment: Any others rules on firewall?

Comment: No rule was added to the firewall. But still what should I look for?

Comment: @Rahatur sorry for the late answer. What you got in apache log files when try to open the website with this rules from allowed IP?